# MySQL: how to trim the content of a cell to make SELECT output more readable

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL table with 6 columns. Some of the columns contain long JSON strings that have newlines and spaces. When I list the content of the table with the SELECT statement, the output is very messy.

Is there a command (or default setting I can change), to limit the output of each column to the first few meaningful characters, so that each row will show as single line regardless of the cell content? Something like:

```
+---------------------------+-------------------------+---------+-----------+--------------+----------+
| jsondata                  | column2                 | column3 | column4   | column5      | column6  |
+---------------------------+-------------------------+---------+-----------+--------------+----------+
| { "Text":[{"user_id":"3","| ABCDEFABCDEFABCDEFABC   |       3 | ABCABCA   | txt          | { "email"|
+---------------------------+-------------------------+---------+-----------+--------------+----------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know about settings that you can permanently change in the DB, but something like this should format the output as you describe it:

```
SELECT column2, column3, column4, column5, REPLACE(CAST(jsondata AS CHAR(20)), '\n', '') AS jsondata FROM tablename;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use TRIM() in your select statement to remove white spaces.

Eg:

```
SELECT TRIM(column_name) AS alias_column_name FROM your_table
```

Also you can use following ways to do this:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING([Column_Name], 1, 100) // Limit to 100 characters
SELECT LEFT([Column_Name], 20) // Get first 20 characters
```

You can do this as follows as well:

```
select
IF(LENGTH([Column_Name]) > 50,CONCAT(LEFT([Column_Name],50),'...'),
[Column_Name]) as [Alias_Column_Name] FROM your_table
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you want the first 15 characters, you can use

```
SELECT LEFT(column_name , 15) FROM table_name
```

If you just want to remove the white spaces, MySQL comes with a `TRIM()` function that returns a string after removing all prefixes or suffixes from the given string.

Syntax of `TRIM()` : `TRIM([{BOTH | LEADING | TRAILING} [remstr] FROM ] str)`

**Example :**

```
SELECT TRIM(TRAILING 'trailing' FROM 'texttrailing' );
```

Using this you can remove the whitespaces from your output.